# Aws step functions - dynamically choosing aub-workflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, dynamic, aws-step-functions

I am putting together a POC to see if AWS step-functions would be a good choice to orchestrate a flow we have.

the basic idea is that we will have a flow with a number of steps in and then at various points we will trigger a aub-workflow (a separate state machine). I am comfortable with how to do that.

however, we will have multiple versions of each sub-workflow (which would each exist as a separate set of steps), and depending on where the initial request came from we would want the flow to trigger a specific version of the sub-workflow.

I thought this might be possible by naming each version of the workflow in a way that would enable us to have a lambda that could build up the Arn of the state machine to trigger based on the incoming request, store it as a variable and pass that variable into the statemachineArn field, something like this...

```
"Parameters": { 
    "StateMachineArn": $.arnToTrigger
```

but when I tried this it didn't work. is anyone able to advise me whether or not what I want to do is possible? I would like to avoid using a choice step as there will be a lot of possibilities and one of the requirements is to add more without having to alter the step functions config

Comment: You want to call other workflows from your main one? Look at writing a Lamda function that uses the Step Functions API to invoke another workflow

Comment: The step functions api has methods called start execution. Here is the offical reference for nodejs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/StepFunctions.html#startExecution-property

Answer (score 0):

Would be better with more code example, but I guess that you should check the way you are passing the parameter from the previous step.
In this case you wrote:

```
"Parameters": { "StateMachineArn": $.arnToTrigger
```

But you should put a ".$" before the key, like:

```
"Parameters": { "StateMachineArn.$": $.arnToTrigger
```

This could be causing your issues.